# What does mean this syntax : window.variable.subvariable = { loading: true };?

Tags: javascript

What are another syntax and signification for this affectation ?

```
window.variable.subvariable = { loading: true };  ?
```

Thanks

Comment: Where did you see this? And what do YOU think it does?

Comment: Why did I get "-4" just for asking a question ? Is it contempt, arrogance ? Do we need all to be specialist for every domain ? Sorry for asking such stupid question. So you can close this website and stay between experts, drinking beers, etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sets `window.variable.subvariable` to an object containing a key `loading` with the value `true`.

You can also directly access `window.variable.subvariable.loading` for setting it to true.

```
window.variable.subvariable = {loading: true};
alert(window.variable.subvariable.loading); // true

// "alternative" syntax
window.variable.subvariable.loading = true;
alert(window.variable.subvariable.loading); // true
```

*Warning:* That the latter way does not overwrite all other values `window.variable.subvariable` might contain.

As a final note, I recommend you reading some basic tutorials about JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

`loading` is a variable on `window.variable.subvariable` (which is an object as you can see in the `{}` syntax)..  You could also access it by `window.variable.subvariable.loading = true;`.  If `window` can be omitted (on pages in web browsers, usually), you don't even have to include `window` In the reference.  You are also defining `window.variable.subvariable` if it was not already defined, too.

Comment: `loading` is not an object. And what makes you so sure that `window` can be omitted? We don't know the environment.

Comment: @zeroflagL Right, fixed.